# Magento 2.2.7 REST API Posting Image fails with 500

Tags: rest, api, post, magento2

I've been using the Magento 2.1.11 web API to upload images to my site for a long time now and everything has been working well. I upgrade to Magento 2.2.7 and now I get a 500 internal server error when I try the same POST request. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Maybe some permissions on the server have changed? I'm struggling to find anything on Google. Below is the request I've been using.

POST {{URL}}/rest/all/V1/products/{{SKU}}/media

```
{
  "entry": {
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "testImage",
    "position":1,
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
      "image"
    ],
    "file": "testFile",
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "base 64 encoded string of image",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "testName.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on Magento 2.2.7. It works for me:

[image]

Can you set mode to developer and send me your error? Or you can check error on the var/log/system.log

You can use this command to set developer mode:

```
php bin/magento d:m:set developer
```